# Getting editor text without html code

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I used CKeditor in my project. I want to record the data which is writed in the CKeditor text to database. When I use to get content from CKeditor I used `CKEditor1.Text` but the problem is that when I record the data it is recorded with together HTML code. For example I have writen in the Ckeditor `Computer Programing` and I selected this write as bold it records the write to database as `<b>Computer Programing</b>`. And I want to record the database same as `Computer Programing` and I want to show to `Computer Programing` in the datalist as bold.

Comment: It sounds like you might to have to store the data in two separate fields, one with the markup and one without.

Comment: yes but I cant do it without the markup

Comment: You can leave it as it is and use a literal in DataList to display `Computer Programming` - It will automatically be displayed as bold.