# how to get plain content from ckeditor

Tags: asp.net

I want to record the text which contents ckeditor to database.When I write something inside ckeditor such as "Stackoverflow" It is recorded to database as < p>Stackoverflow< /p>.My question is that how do I record the data as plain text to database.Namely It is recorded to database as "Staclowerflow"

Comment: You just asked this: [Getting editor text without html code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497967/getting-editor-text-without-html-code)

Comment: I know,because I cant get the answer